# How can I determine to which C standard is this code compliant?

Tags: c

In a C lab this uber simple code appears:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int suma (int a, int b)
{
        return a+b;
}

int mult (int a, int b)
{
        return a*b;
}

int main(void)
{
        int a,b;
        printf ("Operando 1: ");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("Operando 2: ");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        printf("%d+%d=%d\n",a,b,suma(a,b));
        printf("%d*%d=%d\n",a,b,mult(a,b));
        return 0; 
}
```

by looking at the code I'm supposed to determine to which C standard it is compliant (ANSI, ISO or de facto K&R). After reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansi_C) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#ANSI_C_and_ISO_C) I'm inclined to say that it's compliant to the three standards. Would that be correct?

Comment: Did K&R C allow `void` as a parameter type?  And doesn't ANSI or ISO (I forget which) specify that `main` MUST have `int argc` and `char** argv` as parameters?

Comment: @JUST MY correct OPINION: C99 allows for `int main(void)`.

Comment: @JUST: I don't know about the first, but no to the second. Both C89 and C99 require that hosted implementations permit `main` with no parameters (5.1.2.2.1). They also both require that hosted implementations support the `(int,char**)` version. Freestanding environments can do whatever they like.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Hosted environments can do what they like too but it is classed as "implementation defined" i.e. non portable.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I could have sworn that at one point they mandated the `int, char**` version for any compliant system.  Perhaps it was an early draft.

Comment: @JUST MY correct OPINION: In that case the standard is a trap and not very consistent. It first says that they *shall* do such and such and then add the very end of the para it says something like "but you may also do otherwise". And the textual scope of the "otherwise" is not very clear...

Comment: @JeremyP: 5.1.2.2.1/1: "The function called at program startup is named `main`", contrasted with 5.1.2.1/1: "the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined". Hence, freestanding environments can do what they like, and hosted ones cannot. "or in some other implementation-defined manner" means that hosted environments can accept additional forms of `main` if they want, but they still have to permit the program to define it in the two mandated ways.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Yes you are right.  I misread your original post.

Comment: @Mike: K&R usual refers to the pre-standardization language, which was different in several small but telling ways. If you learned c in the 1990s or later you may never have seen any pure K&R code because the language was drifting toward what became the standard through much of the 1980s.

Comment: @dmckee: On the other hand, many programs (including X11!) were compatible with K&R until very recently, so you don't need to be that old to have seen f.e: K&R style function declarations.

Comment: @dmckee, adding to the confusion, the book K&R has been kept up to date with the standard (at least C89). While my copy is a first edition, I'd guess that most people seeing the language for the first time today will not have ready access to the early editions and have to infer what the language used to be from cryptic remarks in various documentation about backward compatibility.

Comment: @RBerteig: Yeah. My *The C programming language* is the 2nd edition (i.e. the '89 language), but I learned in '90 when the ansi standard was still pretty new, so I was shown the old style constructs so I could translate as needed. Is that an edition that covers the '99 standard? I haven't seen one.

Comment: @dmckee, I don't think so and wikipedia at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_%28book%29 seems to concur. I first learned C in about 1983, and I welcomed the improvements that standardization brought. I just never replaced my copy of K&R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not K&R.  K&R function declarations define arguments outside the parentheses like this:

```
int mult (a, b)
    int a;
    int b;
```

and `void` was ntroduced with the first ANSI standard.

To me it looks likeit is compliant with both ANSI C89 and C99.

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to use `gcc`, with the `-std=...`, `-Wall` and `-pedantic` options you may change the standard that it expects and get warning / errors if the code doesn't comply.

Comment: *gasp* But that would be cheating! ;)

Comment: @Tim, but I'd respect the question more if it cited the results of doing just that and asked about the ensuing confusion.... It would also be faster than asking here at all...

Answer (score 3):

I say `C89` (`ANSI C89` or `ISO C90`).

It isn't pre-standard (K&R) C: function definition has type information for parameters inside the declaration.

It follows all rules of the C89 standard and all rules of the C99 standard (*). However, the C99 standard says that `main` returns 0 if it reaches the closing `}` without a return statement. So, the guy who wrote this **had to** add the `return 0;` statement ... or the question doesn't make much sense.

(*) *the first 2 printf shoud really have a '\n' (or call `fflush(stdout);` afterwards) to flush the output*

Comment: Surely the question is, "to what standards does this conform?" not "for what standards is this the typical way to write the code?". I don't think the question makes much sense regardless - (1) who even cares whether code is or isn't K&R C any more, and (2) who formally refers to the standards as ANSI/ISO in preference to C89/C99? So I don't think you should base your answer on an assumption that the question makes sense ;-)

Answer (score 2):

K&R C does not include arguments in function declarations.

See, for instance, [the Wikipedia text on C's history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#History).

Answer (score 0):

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
puts("C99");
#else
puts("C89 or pre C89");
#endif
```

will work for ANSI C compilers.